# Behavior of __str__ in a custom sympy Function?

Tags: python, string, sympy

I would like to have a custom SymPy Function with special behavior when it is converted to a string. The behavior should be like for _latex.

I tried the following code:

```
from sympy import Function, Symbol, latex
class TestClass(Function):
    def _latex(self, printer):
        return 'This is a latex test!'
    def __str__(self):
        return 'This is a str test!'

a = TestClass(Symbol('a'))
ab = TestClass(Symbol('a')) + TestClass(Symbol('b'))
```

The results for

```
print(latex(ab))
print(str(a))
```

are as expected/desired

```
This is a latex test! + This is a latex test!
This is a str test!
```

However, for

```
print(str(ab))
```

the output is

```
TestClass(a) + TestClass(b)
```

How can I archive the desired behavior?

Comment: This is a weird requirement. Adding 2 symbols gives you a single function, so why there would be 2 `__str__` methods called?

Comment: I updated the question. For latex we have the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `_sympystr` method, which accepts a printer.

```py
class TestClass(Function):
    def _sympystr(self, printer):
        return printer.doprint('This is a test!')

a = TestClass(Symbol('a'))
ab = TestClass(Symbol('a')) + TestClass(Symbol('b'))

print(a)
print(ab)
```

Output:

```
This is a test!
This is a test! + This is a test!
```

Note how I called the printer: `printer.doprint('This is a test!')`. In this simple case you could have just returned the string directly. However, if your class contains other sympy objects (symbols, functions, numbers, ...), with this method you can create standard sympy ouput.